# Can't use JavaScriptSerializer in Windows Universal Application

Tags: c#, uwp

I have prototyped getting JSON data from a web service in a Visual Studio 2017 C# console application, deserializing the JSON data into three Strings. Then I moved the code into a Windows 10 Universal application.

The deserialization code won't compile in the UWP program because the type JavaScriptSerializer is not available. I'm unable to add System.Web.Extensions to the system (References/Assemblies/Framework), getting this message from VS 2017, "No framework assemblies found on the machine," when my Windows 10 solution is open.

Here is the JSON string:

```
{  
   "Snippet":"\"Special counsel ...\"",
   "SnippetDate":"9/9/2017 12:00:00 AM",
   "SnippetSource":"The Washington Post"
}
```

Here are the code snippets that compile and run on the console project but not the Windows 10 project.

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
.
.
.

    public class NewsSnippet
    {
        public string Snippet { get; set; }
        public string SnippetDate { get; set; }
        public string SnippetSource { get; set; }
    }

.
.
.

var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var deserializedResult = serializer.Deserialize<NewsSnippet>(jsonString);
```

What alternatives are there to deserialize the JSON String in the Universal Windows application?

Comment: Lookup Newtonsoft's Json.net `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<NewsSnippet>(jsonString);` https://www.newtonsoft.com/json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to add [Newtonsoft's Json.net](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) via [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json)

```
var deserializedResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<NewsSnippet>(jsonString);
var source = deserializedResult.SnippetSource;
```